# Why am I getting a key error in my Django code given below?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

class FormName(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()            
    email=forms.EmailField()
    verify_email=forms.EmailField(label='Confirm your email')
    text=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean(self):  #Allows us to grab all the clean data at once
        all_clean_data=super().clean() #This will clean the entire Form
        email=all_clean_data['email']
        vmail=all_clean_data['verify_email']
        if email != vmail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Make sure your emails match")
```

In this code, I am getting a key error at the line `vmail=all_clean_data['verify_email']`:

```
KeyError: 'verify_email'
```

Answer (score 1):

If a field is invalid, then it will not appear in the form's cleaned data. You can handle this in the form's clean method by using `get()`.

```
def clean(self):  #Allows us to grab all the clean data at once
    all_clean_data=super().clean() #This will clean the entire Form
    email=all_clean_data.get('email')
    vmail=all_clean_data.get('verify_email')
    if email and vemail:
        if email != vmail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Make sure your emails match")
```

For more information, see the docs on [validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the code.
I had a pretty much same code and was experiencing the same error except the fact that i was receiving error for email field as well.Filling the email fields in the browser with .com helped me like instead of filling the email fields like a@b.c,when i filled it with a@b.com,it worked for me.
.co works as well.